# Need help sending mysql result to an array and displaying the results

Tags: php

I have read through many examples and tutorials and can't seem to make this work. I just need to put the results of a mysql query into a php array and then be able to show the results of the array. This is what most examples show, but does not work. I get the error "Notice: Array to string conversion" with a result of Array[0]. Please don't recommend PDO, in the near future, I will be updating my code to use PDO, but have to much to deal with right now, just need this to work.

```
//MYSQL TABLE
category    sub-category
-----------------------------
cars        toyota
trucks        ford

$select = mysql_query("SELECT category, sub_category FROM categories");

data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($select)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo "$data[0][0]<br>";


//EXPECTED RESULT of $data[0][0]
cars

//EXPECTED RESULT OF $data[0][1]
toyota

//EXPECTED RESULT OF $data[1][1]
ford
```

Comment: sorry no idea what this is surpose to be

Comment: It's suppose to show the results of an array that was populated by mysql_query

Comment: there is no query and if you add `print_r($data);` you will see what you have to work with;

Comment: Obviously I have a query, so if it really helps to explain how to display the data, I edited the question and added the query. As for print_r, that is for debugging, not for parsing data and putting into tables.

Comment: well yes, and your debugging right now so um.

Comment: I figured it out. Here is the correct way to do it without using print_r

Comment: as i said before - `print_r` is for debugging

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to display the data from a multidimensional array.

```
data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($select)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

foreach ($data as $results) {
    echo $results['category'];
    echo $results['sub_category'];
}
```

Comment: or just skip the 2 loops, you only actully need one